# Coordinates computation with tkz-euclide

Tags: coordinates, tkz-euclide

In `tkz-euclide`, I want to draw a point with computed coordinates, like in TikZ. However I get a difficult to understand error of syntax which results in a wrong placement. 
The following MWE shows what happens in both cases:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\begin{document} 
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture} .
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\begin{tikzpicture}%[node distance = 2cm, auto] 

\tkzDefPoint[label= left:$O$](0,0){O}
\tkzDrawPoints[size=9,color=red](O)

\coordinate (T) at ({sqrt(4)},0); 
\tkzDrawPoints(T)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](T)


\tkzDefPoint[label= left:$I$]({sqrt(4)},0){I}
\tkzDrawPoints(I)


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The point `O` being the reference the point `T` is defined in classical TikZ and printed correctly while the point I defined in `tkz-euclide` gives a bunch of errors and is drawn at the wrong x-coordinate.

[image]

Of course a work around is to use TikZ instead of `tkz-euclide` to draw points with computed coordinates but it makes the code a bit confusing.

Is there a way to compute points correctly in `tkz-euclide`: `{1+1}` would work but not `{sqrt(4)}`, neither a lot of functions such as `asin`, `acos`, ...?

Comment: Unrelated: the `preview` stuff isn't really necessary when using the `standalone` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tkz-euclide` uses the `fp` package to do the calculations, so the syntax is different. Instead of `sqrt(4)`, you must use `root(2,4)`. The inverse trig functions are `arcsin`, `arccos` etc. See `texdoc fp` (which gives the README file at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fp), lines 139-142 for a list of known operations.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}%[node distance = 2cm, auto] 

\tkzDefPoint[label= left:$O$](0,0){O}
\tkzDrawPoints[size=9,color=red](O)

\coordinate (T) at ({sqrt(4)},0); 
\tkzDrawPoints(T)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](T)


\tkzDefPoint[label= left:$I$]({root(2,4)},0){I}
\tkzDrawPoints(I)


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not clear that the syntax is different, though the manual (very good, in French) p. 154 states (\S 9) that the syntax is different, and even the README file, lines 139-142, if known is not clearer about root(2,4) it is confusing for a normal user. Moreover, the angles are computed in radian while the package uses degree. So the solution is OK but using TiKZ and tikz-euclide will be inconsistent for the syntax while computing all in tikz-euclide will be as inconsistent with some lines of code with angles in degrees and other in radian.